# Is there a way to pass the password to an ssh command using pipes and redirection but without using sshpass and expect tools?

Tags: ssh, passwords

I want to pass the password to an ssh command using linux pipes and redirection without using sshpass utility or expect or ssh keys. Is it possible ?

I tried these :

ssh  | echo "password"

ssh  <  <(echo "password")

But none of them are working

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be technically possible, but it is most probably a **Very Bad Idea** in terms of security.

Tested on a Debian 11 box with Openssh 8.4_p1.

Create an executable script (for example `~/bin/pw_feeder`) :

```
#! /bin/sh
echo 'PASSWORD'
```

Set the `SSH_ASKPASS` and `SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE` environment variables as follows:

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=~/bin/pw_feeder
export SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force
```

You should then be able to connect with `ssh user@host`.

But it means that your password will be stored **in clear text**. It's probably preferable to use pubkey authentication instead, IMO.

---

UPDATE

If you want a solution using Unix pipes, here's a variation.

1. create a named pipe somewhere (e.g. `mkfifo ~/test/pw_fifo`)
2. update the `pw_feeder` script as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -o nounset -o errexit

MY_FIFO=~/test/fifo/pw_fifo

test -p "$MY_FIFO"   ||   { echo "cannot find fifo at $MY_FIFO" >&2; exit 1; }

read -r Password <"$MY_FIFO"
echo "${Password:?missing password}"
```

3. invoke ssh like this: `echo 'PASSWORD' >~/test/pw_fifo & ssh user@host`

This is a proof of concept and could certainly be improved.

Also, be aware that your clear-text password will be visible in your environment and command history.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this using unix pipes and redirection ?

Comment: Appreciate your response. Is it not possible something like this simple command pipes ? For example this works :
# echo | echo "password"
But why doesn't this work :  ssh <IP> | echo "password"

Comment: Possibly, by creating a wrapper for the `ssh` command, but that would be awkward. Can you explain more precisely what you need and why?

Comment: `ssh <IP> | echo "password"` : pipe works from left to right. The output of leftmost command is fed to the standard input of the rightmost command. So the correct way would be `echo "password" | ssh <IP>`, but it will not work because (as far as I understand) SSH forwards its standard input to the remote side.

Comment: Long ago, I remember doing something similar and it succeeded with only pipes and redirection. This will help me to execute just a few lines of bash code at the command prompt itself.

Comment: No idea how to do other than the above solutions.  `sshpass` looks like a suitable tool, though.

Comment: Can anyone give their expert opinions as to why the above simple piping command is not working and a workaround ?